# What is "aio" in Azure JWT token?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

> I am trying Azure Active directory Authentication implementation in
>   the UWP application and getting the token response. My question is
>   what is the meaning claim "aio" in the token?

Comment: I've closed this as duplicate because as mentioned in the other answer, there's no documentation available for this particular claim. What you could do is ask this question here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims and someone from Azure AD team will provide an answer. HTH.

Comment: `aio` stands for "Azure Internal Only" and is an opaque string that should be ignored. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens

Comment: @GauravMantri This is not a duplicate question. The referenced question is very broad and only mentions "aio" as an aside.